# ¿como desplegar una opción del acordeón por medio de una opción en el navbar bootstrap 5?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-5

Muy buenas noches, me encantaría saber como puedo desplegar una opción de un componente de bootstrap en este caso el acordeón, todo desde una de las opciones del navbar, ya que me gustaría crear desde un dropdown varias opciones y que se expanda según el acordeón. el código que tengo es este hasta ahora

```html
<header class="fixed-top">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navigation-wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#inicio">
          <img class="logo" src="img/favicon.png" alt="Logo del Restaurante">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#inicio">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#ubicanos">Ubicanos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                href="#menu">Menús</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <!-- desde estas opciones es lo que quiero que el acordeón se despliege -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#vegetariano">Vegetariano</a></li>
                <!-- opcion keto se despliega cuando escogo la opcion keto del dropdown -->
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#keto">Keto</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#vegano">Vegano</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="col-lg-12 justify-content-center">
        <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#vegetariano" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vegetariano">
                Vegetariano
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="vegetariano" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
              data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/vegetable-skewer-3317060_640.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                        alt="Imagen de brochetas de verduras">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Brochetas de Verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">deliciosas brochetas de verduras frescas, asadas en asador de leña para
                          darte un gusto saludable a tu paladar.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-item" id="keto">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                Keto
              </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo"
              data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/salmon-1238248_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top" alt="Imagen de un plato de salmon">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Salmón con verduras</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Delicionso Salmón acompañado de verduras salteadas y ensalada verde</p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item" id="vegano">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                  Vegano
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree"
                data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                          alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana deliciosa
                          </p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                          alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana deliciosa
                          </p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                          alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                          <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana deliciosa
                          </p>
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                          <img src="img/tomato-4973052_1280.jpeg" class="card-img-top"
                            alt="Imagen de un plato de ensalada de tomate con tofu">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Ensalada de tomate con tofu</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Deliciosa ensalada de tomates frescos con una variante vegana
                              deliciosa
                            </p>
                           <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Añadir</a>
                          </div> 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

En fin según mi código lo que quiero hacer es que cada opción del dropdown despliegue automaticamente la opcion del acordeón pero no he encontrado la forma de lograr dicha funcionalidad, por eso creo que aquí me pueden dar una respuesta gracias.

Comment: Te aseguraste de enlazar los enlaces correspondientes? Prueba poniendo el link del [CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css) al inicio de tu código y script del [JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) al final de tu código...

Comment: Hola Horacio, sería de gran ayuda, que nos mostraras como llamas a tu "css" y a tu "js", y la porción de código de ellos, involucrada en el problema, gracias!!

Comment: Y si lo haces con css puro en lugar de bootstrap??